# How to delete active directory user profile from windows 8 enterprise 64-bit OS?

Tags: user-profile, windows-8

Can anyone help me how to delete active directory user profile in windows 8 enterprise 64-bit Operating System? I'm  trying these steps to delete it but not getting any luck :(. "System Properties" -> "Advanced" -> "User Profiles" -> "Settings" ->"User Profiles" then all Local and Domain Controller profiles are listed but when I try to select domain user profile Delete button is disable and its enable only for selected users.

Answer (score 1):

If you aim to delete the local copy of the user's roaming profile, consider using [delprof2](http://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) - a third party utility similar to Microsoft's delprof available for older OSes.

```
 delprof2 /r /id:<username>*
```

If you do not want to use third party utilities, you might simply delete the `C:\Users\<username>.V2` directory and remove the reference from the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` registry key. The ProfileList uses SID for referencing users so determining the right one to delete would require you to take a look at the ProfileImagePath value which does contain the directory containing the profile on disk.

If you need to delete the roaming profile itself, simply delete the directory containing it on your profiles share. Be aware though that it might "come back" if the user in question has a local copy of the profile at the workstation he logs on the first time after deletion.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete a profile through the regular GUI mechanism if this profile has not been used at all since the last boot of the machine. (Parts of it are still in use if it has been used since last reboot. Running a service on the machine under that user-account als counts as in-use !)

So reboot first. Logon with an account that has local admin rights. Then delete the profile.
There might still remain files on-disk in C:\users. You can delete these safely *after* the profile has been removed.